# How did #806000 get 250,000 views?

Tags: support, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text) has over 250k views.

How did this ridiculous number come about? Was it linked on some TV show or something?

I can't see any sites linking to the question (except the usual SO pages) on Google.

Or is this a normal view count for old popular questions?

Comment: Possibly just a question that lots of people have? It's like Google result #3 for [css transparent background](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20transparent%20background).

Comment: Python + urllib + list of web proxies.  It's 1 possibility anyway.

Comment: Note that the first linked question has over 60K views as well. Common problem...

Comment: [JavaScript: string contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains) has 400K views. I guess a when `title  =  keywords that people search` it translates to crazy high view count

Comment: That's my bad. I just keep forgetting how to do CSS transparent backgrounds and opening that page. For the last 3 years. On different IP addresses. I'm very forgetful you see.

Comment: @BenBrocka I knew I couldn-t be the only one!, It is my most visited bookmark (mmmm... home page counts as bookmark?)

Comment: @lunboks If by number three you mean number one, then yes, you are right.

Comment: @casperOne Number one and two are w3schools.com links.  Number 3 is [this Stack Overflow question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: He probably blocked w3schools links from his results. w3schools, the most annoying website ever.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [That's not how I see it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OU3o5.png) - And I'm not blocking anything.

Comment: @casperOne, weird. Is it possible Google's algorithms have gotten more context-sensitive to the user?  (like somehow they know you really hate w3schools?  :)  )

Comment: @KirkWoll Wait! There are people who *don't* hate w3schools? Isn't that kinda like not hating ewoks?

Comment: @dmckee: Come on, you only missed the Ewok line by *that* much.

Comment: @casper it's probably your location. Google knows it mustn't show crap to cool NY kids

Comment: @pekka we NY kids do get all the cool stuff first

Comment: There is now 860k views.